# Running jUnit with ANT - How to execute all tests without using @Suite?

Tags: ant, junit

I'd like to execute all tests in a /test directory without using annotations such as

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses( ....)
```

In the past i had a single class, which was calling many other classes to test them all. This approach is no longer acceptable.

I have a /test directory, underneath which i have a number of packages, each containing several tests.

In my current `ANT` script, i have:

```
<target name="compileTest" depends="compile" description="compile jUnit">
    <javac srcdir="${test}" destdir="${bin}" includeantruntime="true" />
</target>
```

followed by

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="no" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath location="${bin}" />
        <formatter type="plain" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

In the past, i had

```
<test name="MyCollectionOfTests" />
```

I'd rather not do this anymore.

What am i missing? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested `batchtest`. For instance:

```
<junit printsummary="on"
       fork="on"
       dir="${test.build}"
       haltonfailure="false"
       failureproperty="tests.failed"
       showoutput="true">
  <classpath>
    <path refid="tests.classpath"/>
 </classpath>
 <batchtest todir="${test.report}">
    <fileset dir="${test.gen}">
      <include name="**/Test*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${test.src}">
      <include name="**/Test*.java"/>
      <exclude name="gen/**/*"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```

In its simplest form, you can simply add a nested:

```
<batchtest todir="report">
  <fileset dir="test"/>
</batchtest>
```

to your `junit` call.

Comment: It's a beautiful thing ... THANK YOU